# /usr/ports in OpenBSD

Tags: package-management, openbsd, bsd-ports

From the https://www.openbsd.org/faq/ports/ports.html. "The ports tree is meant for advanced users" .Who is 'advanced user' in OpenBSD world? Make file wizard, Port maintainer, core developer, Theo?

Answer (score 2):

The full paragraph reads:

> The ports tree is meant for advanced users. Everyone is encouraged to use the pre-compiled binary packages. If you have questions about the ports tree, it is assumed that you have read the manual pages and this FAQ, and that you are able to work with it.

An "advanced user" someone preparing or updating a port, or someone working with the ports infrastructure itself, or an admin that needs to build a package from sources for whatever reason (some packages may not be distributed due to licensing restrictions).  Other admins should ideally use `pkg_add` to add pre-built packages, as mentioned in the text above.

It's also worth noting that the quoted text above is just a small bit of the introduction section in a larger document entitled the [OpenBSD Porter's Handbook](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/ports/index.html). The title points to the main audience of the document.

Actually working with packages is described in a totally different section with the title [Package Management](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html). Again, this points to the fact that the Porter's Handbook is mainly for people maintaining ports, or others interested in poking at or learning about the ports infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Kusalananda's answer is sufficient, but I'd just like to add a couple of things.  Porting software to a given OS usually requires patching its source code so that it integrates correctly with the OS - where to install the files, the location of headers and libraries, handling of some of the OS' quirks, etc - which means the porter should have good knowledge of the OS and at least some knowledge about what it being ported.  In this sense, the ports tree, as a repository of porting and packaging code (patches, makefiles, etc) is meant to be used and maintained by the more experienced OpenBSD users and developers.

However, this doesn't mean that it is of no use for everyone else.  In this sense, "advanced users" should be understood as "anyone who is comfortable enough / used to compiling code and using Makefiles" and for some reason needs something different from what the current package provides.  For example, you might need to tweak some compiling option (I, for instance, need R to be compiled to allow `W^X`, because of a specific R library, so I tweak the port's Makefile and rebuild the package), or want to help a port maintainer by testing a patch that hasn't been committed to the CVS repo yet.  Or you might even want to try porting something yourself.

Unless you need to change something that's already packaged or to package something new, it'd be much simpler and quicker to use the pre-built packages.  Otherwise, and if you know your way around Makefiles, feel free to pull a copy of the ports tree and take a look around.